# How to force access to a wifi network on boot up - on an ethernet connected Win 10 desktop

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ethernet

I have wireless router with ethernet links to my TV, NAS and along cable to 2 PCs via a switch. I recently bought a mesh system with 3 nodes because the router was leaving wifi holes around the house. I plugged the main node into last ethernet port on the router, set up the system and connected all my devices to the new wifi network. Everything works perfectly and I have excellent wifi access right through the house. However, my printer and camera are connected to the wifi network and my PCs are on the ethernet and they don't talk to each other. The simple solution was to connect my PCs to the wifi network as well as the ethernet since they both have wifi built in. That also works perfectly - I can connect both PCs to the wireless network and they can then see the printer and are lightening fast. BUT, every time I turn off the PCs they lose the Wifi connection on reboot. It only takes a few seconds to reconnect to the Wifi after booting on but I was hoping someone could tell me how to connect automatically.

PS - I did try removing the PCs from the ethernet altogether and just using Wifi but then the internet access was not so good and they couldn't see the NAS.

Comment: Can you put the mesh on the same subnet as Ethernet?  I did that with my Ubiquiti Access point and wired and wireless all play together.

Comment: Thanks John. It sounds like an ideal solution - if only I knew how to do that! I find networking to be a completely arcane art I'm afraid...

Comment: Log into the Mesh Setup and look in the LAN section. What is the mesh hooked up to (what routing box)?

Comment: Thanks John - you put me on the right track. I checked the IP addresses right across the netword and found that the mesh had created a new network on192.168.5 whereas my ethernet was on the standard 1982.168.1. That's why they werent talking to each other. Fortunately my mesh has an option to create a bridge to the internet facing router. Once I set that up the mesh was brought onto the main network with the router assigning IP addresses to the mesh nodes.. Now everything works fine and I dont need to get my PC onto the wireless network.

Comment: So may I post the answer to this effect since all is working now?

Comment: Yes sure  - its all good now

Comment: You many wish to acknowledge my answer since it did help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the mesh on the same subnet as Ethernet? I did that with my Ubiquiti Access point and wired and wireless all play together.

To do this, log into the Mesh Setup and look in the LAN section. Set this so that everything is on the same network. Then your devices should play together.